# Run script after Jquery finish

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

First let's explain the hack.

When using Total Validator Tool through my web page and I get following error:

> [WCAG v1 6.3 (A), US-508-l] Consider providing a  alternative after each  tag

As my page relies heavily on javascript I can't provide a real alternative, so I thought to add an empty noscript tag after every script appearence. (I know the hack is  silly, let's use it as example material, the point of my post are the final questions)

I tried the following approach:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("script").each(function() {
      $(this).after("<noscript></noscript>");
   }); 
});
```

The problem raises because I have a jQueryUI DatePicker component on my page. jQuery adds a script section after the DOM is ready so my hack fails as miss this section.

So the questions are: How handles jQuery library to be executed after document is ready? How can I run my code after jQuery finish its labours?

Comment: Adding you *really* adding a `<noscript>` tag via JavaScript??

Answer (score 1):

The accessibility tool and the warning message you get are guidelines. To place empty noscript tags afterwards does not improve accessibility, and can only damage your credibility.

The reason you want to pass the test is I guess so you can boast a fully accessible site. I think it is much better to have an accessibility statement explaining all the choices you have made to make the site accessible, and why your site does not pass the test. That would inspire me with more confidence in your accessibility than to have a site pass an automated test.

In short, don't try to trick the test, and the readers, but instead, follow the guidelines, and explain how you have done so.

Comment: Agree with you. I've edited my question to enforce which is the point. Even the example was awful I've still have the doubt: why jQuery is generating html after the $(document.ready)?

Answer (score 1):

```
document.addEventListened('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
    if (e.srcElement instanceof HTMLScriptElement) {
        // a new <script> tag was inserted -> e.srcElement
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you add a `<noscript>` tag via JavaScript that is meaningless, as the `<noscript>` will only be parsed if scripting is disabled in the browser, but if scripting is disabled, the `<noscript>` won't get written at all
2. Have you read the WCAG instead of just blindly trying to fix errors that aren't one? If you can't provide an alternative that is working without scripting, you won't have an accessible document. The first question, that you should ask yourself is: DO I really need that compliance at all? If you do, set up a website that works to 100% without activating JavaScript or any plugins. Afterwards add any scripted enhancements to that site. The method won't require an `<noscript>` tags and it makes your site available to users who have JavaScript disabled.